Looks Like .NET MAUI Is Still Clunky Dealing With iOS's Provisioning Profile "System"
To all:
I've been trying to port an app I wrote last summer in Xamarin Forms over to the latest version of .NET MAUI. I had few issues (but not none) with the Android version, but - as usual - iOS is so arcane that either Microsoft's engineers are missing something, or the process really is still just that bad. And I have 17.12.3, the latest update, too.
TLDR: Nab this repository:
https://github.com/ctmobiledev/DummyDec3-MAUI-iOS
Try it, and see if you get the same thing. On the "Archive Details" dialog, under "Provisioning Profile", I only get the error message "No matching profiles found." And that is JUST after having defined the profile at developer.apple.com!
Below is the latest set of instructions I tried to work through the evening I posted this Many thanks for any insights!
At AppStoreConnect:
Apps >> Register a new app ID
Apps >> “+” (Add) >> Fill out screen:
App ID/Prefix/Team ID
Description
Bundle ID → use reverse domain if you want, say Explicit or “.*” will be required at the end (doesn't mean wild card for any spaces in the name)
Click Register
Go to Apps >> New App
NOTE: may take a few minutes for the new ID to show up (bad performance on Apple's part), refresh the screen with F5 until the drop-down has the ID just entered above.
When done, the Distribution tab/screen should read Prepare for Distribution (yellow light icon).
In Visual Studio (Community Edition):
Restart VS if you haven't already.
Create a new project.
Choose .NET MAUI App template (may need to search for “maui” to find it).
On Configure your new project, select the C:\MAUI folder if it hasn't been selected already.
Click Next.
Leave 8.0 support, click Next.
Click Create, this will generate the base files.
Provisioning and Building:
Right-click on the project name (not the solution name, but the parent right underneath it).
Close (“X”) all the debug windows at screen bottom.
Go to the top of the tree with “Application” and make changes to anything without a “$” symbol.
Open the “iOS” node in the tree at screen left.
Go down to “MAUI Shared”, complete any blanks there.
Scroll past Android to the iOS section, expand the tree at screen left.
Uncheck the LLVM compiler for Release builds.
Bundle Signing section – click on Configure Automatic Provisioning
Try selecting a team. If it fails, close the window and change to Manual Provisioning.
Choose the only iPhone Distribution Certificate (beginning with 2F7)
Leave Provisioning Profile as Automatic.
On the Manifest line, click the link and adjust the Bundle Identifier. Try compiling without adding the 10-char number first.
Change build type to Release if hasn't been done yet.
Do a Clean, and then a Rebuild (which compiles from scratch, not incrementally).
If there are Android licenses needing approval, approve them, then Clean and Rebuild again.
Change the device to the iOS physical device (e.g., “iPhone 12 Device” matching the About page on the iPhone or iPad).
Right-click on the project “head”, one level below the top of the tree. Processing will show “Archiving App Bundle…” The process can take anywhere between 5 and 20 minutes. To see how long the latest build has been going, look at the “Creation Date” field on the second line. NOTE: The Creation Date will change to the compilation completion when it's done.
Creation of IPA file and upload process
This is where .NET MAUI has had problems for me. Can't get to saving to an IPA file.
Click the Distribute… button for the latest build just completed. Double check the archive details in the upper left corner under the screen title to ensure they're correct, especially the bundle iD.
Of the three buttons, click on App Store.
Change the Signing Identity drop-down to the iPhone Distribution option. NOTE: the 10-digit team ID should be selected.
For the Provisioning Profile drop-down, there SHOULD be the provisioning profile ID specified earlier on.
Go back to the CSPROJ file – the second line of the Solution Explorer “tree” and look for iOS, then Bundle Signing. Change back to Automatic Provisioning.
Choose Configure Automatic Provisioning again.
Choose a team. Again, if an error message occurs, exit Visual Studio completely, doing a Save All before exiting.
Restart VS, and even the PC if desired.
Choose the last project edited, it will be on top. Wait for the computer to reconnect to the Mac computer with Pair To Mac (do it manually if needed).
Double-Checking
Go to developer.apple.com and sign in ON THE MAC COMPUTER (not the Windows one running VS).
Click on Profiles.
Locate the App ID defined above.
Select ALL Certificates, all boxes should be checked.
Select ALL Devices, all devices should be checked.
Ensure the name reads: “VS: WildCard Development” exactly.
Click Save.
On the Generate A Provisioning Profile screen, click on Download.
In the browser's Downloads folder, there will be a file called:
VS_WildCard_Development.mobileprovision
Double-click on this file to install it, it will wind up in Xcode, which VS has to “talk” to in order to get ID's and numbers and names correct.
Exit VS and restart it.
Go to the CSPROJ (second line of the tree in the Solution Explorer).
Choose Manual Provisioning.
For Signing Identity, ensure it reads the iPhone Distribution.
For Provisioning Profile, open the drop-down and select VS: WildCard Development.
Right-click on the CSPROJ file.
At this point I gave up. Either I'm missing something, or there's still serious bugs on the iOS side for .NET MAUI. Working with Xamarin Forms last year was complicated, but at least I was finally able to generate something I could upload with Transporter. Can anyone see where I slipped up? Thanks.
The public GitHub repository is here (and it's just a sample project, nothing fancy):
https://github.com/ctmobiledev/DummyDec3-MAUI-iOS
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. I really like how far MAUI has come with Android, but iOS is like programming in the Rosetta Stone. I wonder if I need a special incantation to make this work…

@NotTheDr01ds it was removed because I flagged it and a mod removed it. Reposting likely wouldn’t be a good idea.

In short, I was requesting edits in line with How to Ask so that we could more easily parse the question and come away with a clear idea of 1. Where you were stuck 2. What you tried and 3. What the specific question is that moves you forward. The underlying question could be valuable to others.

@NotTheDr01ds That takes 3 flags which is unlikely to happen that fast…and IV’s original comment was just complaining about downvoters

@Starship-OnDiscussionsStrike It's starting to make sense, I think - It sounds like we may be referring to two different comments then and IV might have already reposted after the first was deleted.  Then the second was also deleted as the Mod just removed the entire thread, even though that last one was really useful. After I refreshed the page, all the comments has been removed. (Side note - I'm cleaning up my no-longer-needed comments above as well ;-)

I have too much respect for the community to ever disparage anyone who votes. The OP describes a greater level of difficulty deploying iOS platform, it can be capricious. I was doing my best to express that while OP and I share a perception of the greater day-to-day challenges of working with MAUI.iOS, it doesn't change the fact that a question needs to be actionable and answerable, and that if it isn't then it's unlikely to get good reviews. My wording evidently left room for that to be misconstrued, but all I ever meant to say is that we're in the same boat when it comes to MAUI.iOS.

Maybe I can help with what I learned when Apple recently (or so) made a breaking change to the flow where "old" provisioning profiles no longer worked, and new ones (for me at least) wouldn't work either, even for a brand new default MAUI project. What I had to do was go to App Store Connect (not Apple Developer) because the new process requires an API key that resides there.


Next I had to remove everything in Tools\Options\Xamarin\Apple Accounts and create new from that credential.


To your point, I spent easily more than a full day trying to get past this next dialog by downloading credentials, using openSSL and command line to turn .p8 into .p12 so I could try and import into the "local keychain". In short, Automatic Provisioning was giving me one and only one choice for Team and then rejected it when I tried to apply it in the project.


In the end
What made Auto Provisioning work again, and I'm not necessarily proud of doing this, but I uninstalled Visual Studio. That's right. The rationale was that this new flow was supposed to be seamless and automagic so I figured some cached value in some ¿quién sabe? location was gumming up the works. I uninstalled it, went into app data and removed residual, and installed Visual Studio again. I also went to Apple Developer and tried to delete everything from before the purge in order to induce the API key into making everything anew.
And before anyone judges me too harshly on this one, it does work now the way it's supposed to. So, I'm sharing my personal journey, my "special incantation" in hopes that it might help you if you haven't solved this already on your own.

Thanks, IV! I actually managed to find out a way forward; I just hadn't documented it here formally yet. And it (thankfully) didn't require uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio (although I'll have to keep that as a tactic for down the line). Another comment elsewhere on another thread said that Visual Studio DOES NOT automatically "sync" the provisioning profiles - it theoretically should, but it doesn't. It seems to do okay if you're doing development only ("VS: WildCard Development") but when it's time to release, it fails. I wound up manually copying the profiles over to my PC.

For sure! And if you do get around to documenting that in the form of a self-answer, I for one would upvote it provided that you explain how you got the profiles that you manually copied into the 'local' keystore on the remote client (pc-side)! For me, Visual Studio kept showing e.g. three profiles where only one of them was valid in terms of finding a certificate. I definitely share your overall sentiment of feeling like you hit the lottery any time you get the iOS side to deploy.

To wit, the VS: WildCard Development certificate that had worked before, no longer had a certificate under Apple's new rules. Oh, and p.s. I had some luck "re-syncing the profiles" by removing the provisioning entries from the .csproj and restarting the Configure Automatic Provisioning flow. In my environment, that seems to be the moment the fetch occurs.
